# How can I send keyboard commands to pc from android app over bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to build an app similar to the attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaGjq.png)

The app will send keyboard commands like 'Crtl+c' to my PC. Can anyone please suggest me how can I build one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Android pie and later by using the HID device profile. You can get the BluetoothHidDevice proxy object using the method BluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you provide any tutorial link?